# RegEx teaser

Tags: php, regex

Let's say we have 2 php variables:

- **$name** = 'caption';
- **$url** = 'http://domain.com/photo.jpg';

The input string of `'{@url,<img src="," alt="{@name}" />}'` should return:

`'<img src="http://domain.com/photo.jpg" alt="caption" />'`

The `{tag}` takes up to 3 parameters: `{@variable[,text_before][,text_after]}`.

What regex would be needed to make this happen? The tricky part is that a `{@..}` tag is nested within another.

Comment: Are you deliberately not using an already-existing PHP templating engine?  :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you've come across one of those situations where you *shouldn't* use regex.

much like this one.

[Multi-Line group and search with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154708/multi-line-group-and-search-with-regex)
[Multi-Line group and search with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154708/multi-line-group-and-search-with-regex#162194)

Comment: To elaborate on that, you can't really parse a recursive syntax reliably with a regular expression.  Since this syntax seems to be recursive, a regular expression in this case is probably a mistake.

Answer (score -2):

It's for a CMS. Admins can add column fields, then add template code for how it will be displayed on the listing page. The {@tags} are used to output the dynamic column values. This template code:

`<p>Link: <a href="{@url}">{@name}</a> - {@date}</p>`

would create a listing page like:

Link: [link one](http://google.com) - 2 July 2008

Link: [link two](http://google.com) - 14 June 2008

Link: [link three](http://google.com) - 9 February 2007

...

I figured that people might want to use column values within others, hence the "alt" tag example from the first post. So using regex for this would be a bad idea?

Comment: I think your example didn't demonstrate that very well, it looked to me like you could have written it how I did in my answer. Am I mistaken?

And yeah, if'n you're separating by commas, $str = explode(',', $str) makes the most sense.